# Input shape and Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, training-data, keras-layer

I have a set of training data where each input is a vector of length 138. I have 519 of these vectors for a batch size of 519. These are not images, just real-valued numbers.

I'm trying to start with a 2 layer dense Keras model:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(200, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=[138]),
    layers.Dense(200, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    layers.Dense(1)
])
```

When I build the model I get the following error:

```
Error when checking input: expected dense_27_input to have shape (138,) but got array with shape (519,).
```

Where in Keras do I distinguish batch size from number of input features? `layers.Dense()` seems to assume that my input is in rows vs. columns.

Comment: Can you show the instruction where you input the vectors in the model ?

Comment: What is the shape of input array, `(138, 519)` or `(519, 138)`?

Comment: The shape of the input array is 138x519. The instruction where I put the input vectors in the model is:   example_batch = normed_train_data[:10]
example_result = model.predict(example_batch) where   def norm(x):
  return (x - train_stats['mean']) / train_stats['std']
normed_train_data = norm(train_dataset). I've been following this example: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_regression

Answer (score 1):

Keras expects the first axis to be the batch axis. Therefore if you have 519 training samples where each one is a vector of length 138, the array you pass to the `fit` method must have a shape of `(519, 138)`. So if currently the array of training data has a shape of `(138, 519)`, simply transpose it to make the shape consistent:

```
import numpy as np

train_data = np.transpose(train_data)
```